# Magento: redirect to the home page from a template?

Tags: magento, redirect

I am in catalog\product\compare\list.phtml and I want to redirect to the homepage, like this:

```
if($someThing) {
    // redirect to homepage
    $this->_redirect('home'); // --> doesnt work
    $this->_redirect(Mage::getBaseUrl()); // --> doesnt work
}
```

I tried several things, none worked so far. How do I do it right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know the $this->_redirect can only be used in a controller.

Try this instead:

```
    Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($this->getBaseUrl());
```

Answer (score 2):

try below

```
header("Location:".Mage::getBaseUrl());
exit();
```

Or

```
 Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
exit();
```